# Ubuntu sdk-cannot create click package and cannot create emulator

Tags: ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-sdk, click-packages

I have been trying to create a click package in the Ubuntu sdk however I am unable to do so.The reason is because the "click" column in the publish tab is missing.I only have the validate column...[image]

Another problem I have is that I am unable to create new emulators.I only have a 'cat:' emulator which does not work.Every time I try to create a new emulator,the new emulator is not displayed under devices or anywhere else.I also can't remove the 'cat:' emulator.I can only remove it from ->tools->options,however every time I restart qt creator,the 'cat:' emulator is back.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems:

1. Click package creation is possible only for phone or emulator target. The click package reation is disabled when your target is the desktop.
2. You have a broken emulator on your machine. It is a know and fixed bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu/+bug/1409596 The today's release contains the fix for it.